# Notation for Legendre symbol over polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Hopefully this is a simple question to answer. I am wondering if there is any standard notation for something equivalent to the Legendre symbol, but over polynomial rings. That is, if we have a prime $q$, is there a standard notation to indicate whether some $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is a square or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we have an analogy of $\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb F_p[X]$, and we can also look at quadratic reciprocity in $\Bbb F_p[X]$ via Euler's criterion.
The details can be found in [Lemmermayer](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiTprmz6bLzAhXJg_0HHcxRAK0QFnoECCUQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fen.bilkent.edu.tr%2F%7Efranz%2Fnt%2Fch12.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Z2yIl9OGssQHUn_jenbd6), section $12.2$:

If $P$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ odd, and $NP=p^{{\rm deg}(P)}$, then $f^{NP−1}\equiv 1\bmod P$, hence
$$
0=f^{NP−1}-1=(f^{\frac{NP−1}{2}}-1)(f^{\frac{NP−1}{2}}+1)
$$
Since $P$ is prime we conclude that $f^{\frac{NP−1}{2}}\equiv \pm 1 \bmod p$.
Now define the Legendre symbol by
$$
\left( \frac{f}{P}\right):=f^{\frac{NP−1}{2}}\bmod P.
$$
And indeed we have $\left( \frac{f}{P}\right)=1$ if
$f\equiv g^2\bmod P$ is a square modulo $P$.